# [meta] tag on SO used for multiple purposes - how to handle?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

Currently the `[meta]` tag is being used for two purposes:

1. Belongs-on-Meta-SO

   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109179/how-to-insert-sample-xml-code-in-stackoverflow-closed
   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090166/openid-account-got-disconnected-from-stack-overflow-account-closed
2. Meta-information (for example, HTTP headers)

   - [Are there situations in which the following forwarding doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888703/are-there-situations-in-which-the-following-forwarding-doesnt-work)
   - [Dynamically adding meta tags using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028211/dynamically-adding-meta-tags-using-php)

I think they should be separated into separate tags, or perhaps the former type deleted? What do you suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of any real usage (like the `<meta>` tag in some markup languages), it *definitely* should not be used for tagging questions that belong on Meta. Questions that belong on Meta should be asked on Meta, not on Stack Overflow, so we don't need a category on Stack Overflow to identify those questions. If you see a question tagged Meta for being asked on the wrong site, please retag where you can and flag things like migration stubs.

Other users who think a question belongs on Meta should express this by voting to migrate it, not retagging. If it's the author who intentionally tags it as Meta in order to prompt moving it here, that is bad practice - one should be asking questions on the correct site, not waiting for migration to happen.

Comment: I don't think it's the original author tagging as `[meta]`, it's perhaps users with enough rep to retag, but not enough to cast a close vote? Either way, this sounds like the right answer.

Comment: Ok, there are only about 90 questions, so I'm going to go through and clean it up (and flag where I can't)...

Comment: Ack, ran out of flags. Posted a retag request here instead: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54956/retag-request-remove-meta-tags-on-so-for-questions-where-it-means-belongs-on